# htaccess rewrite condtion only for specific domain not sub folder

Tags: apache

My current code is this

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://example.com/
Redirect 301 /about.html http://example.com/
Redirect 301 /contact.html http://example.com/contact.php
```

However this is affecting another domain that points to a sub folder of this site.

is there a way to say something like if(DOMAIN != 'example2.com'){...}

i also use other RewriteRule functions like this

```
RewriteRule ^events/?$ events_page.php [L]
```

and also this to remove www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a particularly elegant way, but the following should do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example2\.com
RewriteRule /(index|about)\.hmtl http://example.com/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example2\.com
RewriteRule /contact\.hmtl http://example.com/contact.php [R=301,L]
```